# "Logging out" of phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, configure

The error that I get on phpMyAdmin is the following

```
The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated."
```

I have googled and looked this up for a while now and the common answer that comes up is to Log Out/In or the clear the cookies and cache. Clearing the cookies and caches did not work for me. I have tried to logout, but cannot seem to be able to find out how to, because in the updated version of phpMyAdmin, I believe that there is no logout button as opposed to the older versions which is why people posted that as a solution before. I am not sure what version of phpMyAdmin I have because I downloaded it through xampp, but this is what mine looks like: [image]

Comment: You did not specified the version you are using so no comparison can be made.

Comment: @Gimmy How can I check what version I downloaded, because I believe I downloaded it through xampp? (Also updated question with image)

Comment: The version of phpMyAdmin is located on the bottom right corner of the page in the "phpMyAdmin" section.

Answer (score 54):

[image]

click on this button out your phpAdmin home page

Comment: I have no such button.

Comment: This button does not always exist. Can you send the link of the button when you hover over it?

Comment: @JonasMerhej the link looks like http://localhost/phpmyadmin/logout.php?db=&token=07c14c216cb42b675637b66ff28013ec

Answer (score 43):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23524894/791746) and i quote:

> just change this line on **config.inc.php**
>
> ```
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
> ```
>
> then you will be prompted
>   to login when you refreshed the page. Afterwards, the log out icon
>   will appear next to home icon.

Answer (score 13):

The second button from the left.  The one on the right of the house in the image you posted is your logout button.

For your error message try this link in the documentation:
http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Configuration_storage

Make certain you have a phpadmin control user account created.  This is covered in the second paragraph in on the documentation page in the link.

Comment: That button opens a query window (PHPMyAdmin v4.1.6)

Comment: That button opens a query window (PHPMyAdmin v3.5.8.2)

Comment: You're right.  The OP's icon picture shows 5 icons.  I have 6 icons on l my phpmyadmin installs.  There is a logout icon between the home icon and the query icon.  Both the logout and query icon has a green arrow as part of the icon.  I mistook position of his query icon as the logout icon.  Since you (and the OP) appear to be missing the logout icon (one of the default six that has been in all my installs since v3.3), you appear to have a faulty installation.  Try a fresh install.  In the meantime I'll try a few and see if I can experience the problem you're getting.

Answer (score 9):

### In one click

Logout from PhpMyAdmin with URL like `/phpmyadmin/index.php?old_usr=xy`

> *source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23143634/4457531*

---

**EDIT:** *It works with PhpMyAdmin version `4.0.10.18`?*

Answer (score 2):

The presence of the logout button depends on whether you are required to login or not, in the first place. This is tweakable in PHPMyAdmin config files.

Yet, I don't think that would change anything concerning your error message. You would need to fix the configuration for the message to go away.

Edit: [this is](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/238880-phpmyadmin-how-to-set-up-configuration-storage-to-enable-extended-features/#entry1227993) the kind of solution you should be searching for. And here are [plenty of others](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22configuration%20storage%20is%20not%20completely%20configured,%20some%20extended%20features%20have%20been%20deactivated&oq=%22configuration%20storage%20is%20not%20completely%20configured,%20some%20extended%20features%20have%20been%20deactivated&aqs=chrome.0.57.538&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for you to explore ^^

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the current account you have used to log in probably has very limited priviledges.

To fix this problem, you can change your the AllowNoPassword config setting to false in `config.inc.php`. You may also force the authentication to use the config file and specify the default username and password .

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; // leave blank if no password
```

After this, the PhPMyAdmin login page should show up when you refresh the page.
You can then log in with the default root password.

More details can be found on [this post ..](http://denvycom.com/blog/phpmyadmin-database-no-priviledges/)

Answer (score -1):

Simple seven step to solve issue in case of **WampServer**:

1. Start WampServer
2. Click on Folder icon Mysql -> Mysql Console
3. Press Key Enter without password
4. Execute Statement

   ```
   SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('root');
   ```
5. open D:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php file 
   set value

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
   ```
6. Restart  All services
7. Open phpMyAdmin in browser enter user root and pass root

Comment: The question is about `xampp`, not `wamp`.