# How do I logout of phpMyAdmin 4.x - probably with a "hack"?

Tags: phpmyadmin

For some reason, in this version, they decided we don't need a logout button anymore!?

VERY frustrating, as I switch between databases all day long, and my 'best' option so far is to log right out of my hosting, log back in, launch phpmyadmin, then log into that!

Does anyone know a url variable, or actual link to go to to log out?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, 4.x? Please tell us the exact version number. By the way, the logout button has not been removed in any version, but you'll see it only if you logged in. If your credentials are hard-coded in config.inc.php and you are using the 'config' authentication type, you did not log in.

Comment: This particular version is: phpMyAdmin 4.1.12

Comment: And what is your authentication type in config.inc.php ?

Comment: @MarcDelisle I'm using phpMyAdmin version 4.0.10.18 through namecheap, and the logout button disappeared. Granted I'm using it through CPanel, idk if the sessions are tied together so no logout button is needed; I just assumed CPanel logged me in, and I wanted to make sure the session got cleaned up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try modifying the path of your url to `/phpmyadmin/index.php?old_usr=whatever` in the browser. They may have disabled the link, but left the code that handles the logout call installed.

Comment: INDEED: ?old_usr=whatever Does log you out - Thanks!

Comment: OK - This doesn't work anymore!  Looks like they found our little 'hack' and decided letting us log out this way is some sort of problem.  Now it lands you on a page with a security token issue......WOW - I can't believe they would do this.

Comment: Here's the message: Functions in cPanel / WHM are available only directly through the cPanel and WHM interfaces or through our XML API. The administrator of the system has enabled additional security token checks which have flagged this request as possibly malicious. This may be due to an expired session cookie or the use of an older theme which has not been updated to work with the security token system.

Comment: Sorry @kandu, looks like you should change hosting providers... If they are bent against you using this functionality, they will keep blocking you.

Comment: I'm using version 4.0.10.18, and this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

1) I do not have this version at hand, but maybe there is some small button in the upper right area on the right side, to the right of the "home" button. The one with a little green arrow pointing to the right is the logout button, if youhave it.

2) Very unlikely on a server of a hosting company, but maybe someone else who comes from a google search needs this information:

This can happen if you are not logged in, because the instance of phpmyadmin is configured to not need a login and be freely accessible. This can be changed in the configuration.

3) This is not answering your question directly, but maybe you could install your own instance of phpmyadmin using its latest downloadable package on the same hosting account and configure it to your needs. Maybe on a subdomain of one of your projects, if it is technically possible to access all the databases from it.

Comment: #1 - nope.  the home button, refresh, info etc....I don't think anything up there has changed EXCEPT they have removed the logout.

#2 -> agreed, why in the WORLD would they do this!?  it's dumb, I've contacted my hosting, they say it's not even a problem this way!  wow.

Not sure what is going on with this version, but I can't wait till they get their heads out of their a##.

Comment: @kandu Don't blame phpmyadmin.. I got the link by looking at the logout button. I bet it is some customization that your hosting service has done or some skin that removed that button. It is there on the default phpmyadmin console.

Comment: @kandu I confirm that this is part of a customization, most likely done by cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I use the version 4:3.4.11.1-2 on Debian,
like mit said I'm able to log out with the second button on the left, right above the information_schema db. A butto with an icon like a small open door with a green arrow pointing to the... **left**! :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @kandu.  This appears to be a customization done by the web host through their cPanel.  If you access phpMyAdmin through your web host's cPanel like me, then you should be able to logout out of cPanel, and this will also logout of phpMyAdmin.  Note that this will not close your phpMyAdmin browser window, but you will get an access error if you try to do anything (since you are now logged out).  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me, was deleting the session cookie.
(In browser dev tools > Storage > Cookies)