# cannot log-out from phpmyadmin in XAMPP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have completely set up my xampp with username and password.
Once I have logged in, I cannot seem to find a way to log-out.
No button for log-out can be seen near the home button at the left sidebar.
Please help. This is getting in my way to create a web application. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to logout? Just close the window/tab. Why is this "getting in your way" to create a web application?

Comment: It's for security purposes. My database will contain all vital information about my web application. I don't want any other people using my laptop be able to open the phpmyadmin. Thanks tho.

Comment: Then use your browsers "private session" feature or remove all history and cookie data after usage. You have to anyway if you share a desktop session. But one question: why do you share your desktop account with other people you do not trust? That makes no sense at all!

Comment: I shouldn't remove anything. I just only need to log-out, it will solve everything without deleting any history or cookie. I am not sharing my desktop account for nonsensical purposes, it just happened that I have to create an app which must be testable with my friends. If you don't know the answer, it's fine.

Comment: As said before: that is what the "private session" feature in todays browsers is for.

Comment: Sorry but not all browsers have private session, and that would still basically not solve the problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't that solve the problem? It prevents any history data or cookies from that session to be stored. That is _exactly_ what you are  looking for. There are still browsers without that feature? Then use another one, I'd say. But it's fine if you don't like using that feature. I suggest that you implement a logout button into your phpmyadmin installation then. Shouldn't be too complicated. But take care how to do that. Just because you press some logout button somewhere does _not_ mean that your previous session cannot be misused by others.

Comment: Yet another example of the arrogance of people on stackoverflow thinking they are better than everyone else. @arkascha it is people like you who ruin this community for everyone else.

Comment: @arkascha Why don't you just tell us the answer to the question? No one asked about the sense or nonsense of a logout button. Honestly, I personally also prefer to be able to logout. Especially, since I'm willing to use my phpmyadmin remotely also from other computers.

Comment: @PeMa Thanks for pointing this out after such a long time. You do have a point there.

Comment: @user3205578 I do apologize for not sticking with the actul question asked and issue discussed. Those comments I meant initially tried to point out that such a missing feature are not the end of the world and that there are workarounds, I simply could not accept your statement that this "is getting in your way when developing a web application"... However I do understand that this was not constructive in any way and probably annoyed you. I do apologize for that.

Comment: @arkascha why couldn't you accept my statement "is getting in your way when developing a web application"? It is something that you would understand if you are on a software development project with agile sprints running on a story (Jira). I simply cannot bypass the current sprint for environment provisioning (standing up servers and securing them) before delving to the actual web application development per se. I hope this enlightens you.

Comment: This isn't a simple project where you can just jump to tasks and skip something as I was in-charged with security, task management and the actual web development as well.

Comment: And also to point out, sometimes workarounds are not the actual solution to the problem like the answer below. I wouldn't want to add another process or step no matter how small it is if there is a solution that would simplify the equation like the answer posted below. @arkascha

Comment: Apart from that I fail to make more sense of the statement in your comment above. What do you mean by "standing up servers"? What do you mean by "I simply cannot bypass the current sprint"? What has provisioning got to do with access to a database? And what sense does the string "before delving to the actual web application development per se" try to express?

Comment: @arkascha Sorry I can't keep on explaining on the processes that we currently follow. We aren't on the same wavelength on the strategies to executing a software development project. You have to be involved with our agile process to understand what I'm saying. Have a good one mate!

Comment: Also, my comments from above explain everything. Just use them as a reference to understand "is getting in your way when developing a web application" statement. @arkascha

Comment: All the best to you! Great to hear that you follow agile principles, love that myself. Though I am surprised that apparently you are still working on the same project after 2,5 years? I hope you are not still blocked by this issue... But seriously: take care, and good luck!

Comment: @arkascha cheers, mate. I was surprised actually that this question surfaced again. I'm still involved with the same team, though. thanks! all the best to you as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Logging out" of phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873448/logging-out-of-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

just change this line on `config.inc.php`

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

then you will be prompted to login when you refreshed the page. Afterwards, the log out icon will appear next to home icon.

Answer (score 1):

By default, phpMyAdmin stores the username and password for
MySQL's root user in its configuration file, which is a plain text file. Since this
isn't secure, it's generally considered a good practice to modify these default
settings.............see below

**The default location of the config file for phpMyAdmin**

C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin conno. Inc.php

**How to configure authentication for phpMyAdmin**

1.Open the config. ine php file in a text editor such as Notepade.

2. Set the 'blowfish secret option to a random 32 character siring. The specifies the
   encryption key for the cookie.
3. Set the auth_type' option to a value of cookie.
4. Set the 'user' and password' options to empty strings as shown below.
5. Save your changes.

**The default settings**

```
$cfg('blownah secret') = 'xampp' /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SE-
CURE COOKIE AUTH! */
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

**The settings after phpMyAdmin has been configured for authentication**

```
$cfg('blowfish_secret') = 'Ak20vo93me201290184pb56nedIwa70';
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

**How to use phpMyAdmin to test the MySQL server and set a password**

1. Use the XAMPP Control Panel to start the Apache and MySQL servers
2. Use the XAMPP Control Panel to start phpMyAdmin To do that, click on the Admin
   button for MySQL. This should start phpMyAdmin and prompt you for a username
   and password. If it doesn't, click the "Log out" link to display a "Login" page,
3. Log in as the root user by specifying a username of 'root' By default, the root user
   doesn't have a password, so you don't need to enter one. When you successfully
   log in as the root user, phpMyAdmin should display its Home page. At this point,
   both the MySQL server and phpMyAdmin are working correctly.
4. Click the Change Password link in the General Settings section, enter and re-enter a
   password, and click the Go button.
5. Log out by clicking the Log Out icon near the upper left corner of the page, and
   then log back in using the new password.