# mySQL connection won't work

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I just can't connect to mySQL using Eclipse and can't figure out why.

Here is my connection class :

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class ConnexionBDD {

static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/Peoples?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
static String login = "root";
static String password = "";

static Connection connection = null;
static Statement statement = null;
static ResultSet result = null;
static String request = "";

public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println("will load driver");
    loadingDrive();
    System.out.println("will connect");
    connection();

}

public static void loadingDrive() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}

public static void connection() {
    try 
    {
       connection =  (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
       System.out.println("Connected");
       statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();

       result = statement.executeQuery(request);

    } 
    catch ( SQLException e ) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if ( result != null ) {
            try {
                result.close();
            } catch ( SQLException ignore ) {
            }
        }
        if ( statement != null ) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch ( SQLException ignore ) {
            }
        }
        if ( connection != null ) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch ( SQLException ignore ) {
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the result in the console :

```
will load driver
will connect
Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

I have the connector (mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar) in the file WebContent/WEB-INF/lib.

I installed mySQL on my mac.
I installed MAMP, I can reach phpmyadmin and add a new database, but it's kind of weird though, phpmyadmin is already logged as default and clicking the "Exit" button does not disconnect me I don't know why..

The url of phpmyadmin is :
     http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/index.php

Why can't I connect to mySQL ?

EDIT :
I changed my url with the right port (8889) after checking out the mySQL port on MAMP, but nothing changed in the output of the console.

Comment: If phpmyadmin is on port 8888, then I don't think your mysql can also be on port 8888. Can you check that?

Comment: may you post the connection String?

Comment: apparently it's 8889 but changing this in the url does not change the result on the console.

Comment: what do you mean by connection string ?

Comment: the url parameter of getConnection method

Comment: it is defined at the top of the class, it is :
jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/Peoples?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false

Comment: print the stack trace of exception, so You can have useful information regarding what is going wrong.  In your code just add e.printStackTrace(); in your catch statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL and phpMyAdmin cannot be on the same port.

Are you sure that your MySQL is not running on the default port? 3306

UPDATE:

If you are not already using Maven, please do so. It will aid you in managing your packages. That way you can avoid your method: `loadingDrive()`

I just ran you code locally with a test database. It runs fine for me.

I did the following changes to your code:

I removed the `loadingDrive()`
Altered `request` to `static String request = "SELECT 1";`. This query string is good for testing if the connection to the database is working properly.

I printed the request to the console:

```
result = statement.executeQuery(request);

System.out.println(result.next());
```

I added the mysql jdbc connector to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

After this I ran the code and this is the console output:

```
will connect
Connected
true
```

I still think your MySQL port is wrong. Do you run MySQL locally? Can you connect to it with phpMyAdmin?

I tried to change the `url` to contain the wrong port. I then received:

```
Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

So I strongly believe that your port is wrong. Can you try to change your `url` to the following?

```
static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Peoples?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
```

Comment: apparently it's 8889 but changing this in the url does not change the result on the console.

Comment: I have updated my answer after running your code. I could execute your code succesfully without error. Please let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, well the weird thing is that phpmyadmin is always logged in and that I just cannot log out when I click on "Exit", other than that I can create databases, tables and so on, so I guess mySQL is running correctly (MAMP also says mySQL is On). However I just can't figure out what the login and password is, as I can't log out, I tried to create a new user via phpmyadmin and connect with its login information but it still does not work. 

The port was wrong, it actually is 8889, I changed it but I still can't connect..

Comment: No problem. Atleast you now know that your code can run.  I havnt used phpMyAdmin for the last 7 years, I am used to interact with mysql with either a console or mysql workbench.

So I do not know why you cannot log out. But if you can execute queries in phpMyAdmin, then you can create a new user and try to connect with that user in Java. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

 (I suggest you to stop using phpMyAdmin and use mysql workbench instead)

Comment: I know that you are using MAMP, but XAMPP is very similar. I might have found a solution for your logout problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427098/cannot-log-out-from-phpmyadmin-in-xampp